# Format List of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents

I am working on a thesis, I use report document, I need to format a list of figures as shown in the image:
[image]

The same heading should be repeated in all LOF pages. The "List of Figure" should be in centered and 16px.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are supposed to add that to the real list? Usually, those are instructiin how to lay out the page. In this case, this would be the default layout.

Comment: Yes, but your comment is not helpful!.